# cod4 on wine problem

Tags: wine

I install cod4 on ubuntu 13.10 and everything is ok but when i connect to server cod4 just freez and send me an error iw3mp.exe has stoped working. any halp pls and thank you
I google it and win users tell that is because one of this is problem - Uninstalled audio driver and let Windows reinstall driver.
- Installed newest Realtek driver.
- Changed file name in Mile.
- Plugged in mic.
- Enabled steriomix.
 and i realz dont know how to fix it. I postet to wine but no one replaz to me so i ask here

Answer (score 0):

Did you use [Playonlinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/)? If you didn't, i recommend doing so.

According to [WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=12804) it should run just fine.

ps: Playonlinux has pre-written install scripts that make installing windows games on linux a breeze (if they are supported, ofc.).

Quick description on Playonlinux:

> PlayOnLinux is a piece of software which allows you to easily install
>   and use numerous games and apps designed to run with Microsoft®
>   Windows®. Few games are compatible with GNU/Linux at the moment and it
>   certainly is a factor preventing the migration to this system.
>   PlayOnLinux brings a cost-free, accessible and efficient solution to
>   this problem. What are PlayOnLinux's features?
>
> Here is a non-exhaustive list of the interesting points to know:
>
> - You don't have to own a Windows® license to use PlayOnLinux.
> - PlayOnLinux is based on Wine, and so profits from all its features    yet it keeps the user from having to deal with its complexity.
> - PlayOnLinux is free software.
> - PlayOnLinux uses Bash and Python.
>
> Nevertheless, PlayOnLinux has some bugs, as every piece of software:
>
> - Occasional performance decrease (image may be less fluid and graphics    less detailed).
> - Not all games are supported. Nevertheless, you can use our manual    installation module.

Source: http://www.playonlinux.com/en/